Bigquery issue - UNNESTING Item table - Inflating Totals from GA4 data
enter image description hereI running the following query for GA4 data in Biogquery. Without any other columns just running Total Revenue and Total Sessions, I getting the results I need to be brought into Tableau. Here is the rub...When I first ran this query, I was UNNESTING(Item) right under the FROM clause. This was incorrect. I then did some research and found that I could UNNEST right under the SELECT statement (like you see below). The problem is this. When I include the Item_name and Item_category using Max in front of it inflates the total revenue and total number of sessions. I have other columns I need to include but, I want to work small at first and later bring in the remaining columns. What am I doing wrong?
SELECT
    event_date,
    --event_name,
    MAX(item_names) AS item_names,
    MAX(item_category) AS item_category,
    COUNT(DISTINCT CONCAT(user_pseudo_id, COALESCE(session_id, 0))) AS Total_sessions,
    COALESCE(SUM(total_revenue), 0) AS Total_Revenue
FROM (
    SELECT
        event_date,
        event_name,
        user_pseudo_id,
        (SELECT STRING_AGG(item_name, '; ') FROM UNNEST(items)) AS item_names,
        (SELECT STRING_AGG(item_category, '; ') FROM UNNEST(items)) AS item_category,
        (SELECT COALESCE(SUM(item_revenue_in_usd), 0) FROM UNNEST(items)) AS total_revenue,
        (SELECT value.int_value FROM UNNEST(event_params) WHERE key = 'ga_session_id') AS session_id
    FROM
        xxxxxx-xxxxxxxx-xxxxx.xxxxxxxxx_xxxxxxxxx.xxxxxx_*`
    WHERE
        event_date >= '20230101'
) grouped_data
GROUP BY
    event_date,
    event_name

I have tried UNNESTING (Items) first yielding the inflated results. I have also tried (SELECT STRING_AGG(item_category, '; ') FROM UNNEST(items)) AS item_category and I have also tried the below query as well:
SELECT
    MAX(item_names) AS item_names,
    MAX(item_category) AS item_category,
    COUNT(DISTINCT CONCAT(user_pseudo_id, COALESCE(session_id, 0))) AS Total_sessions,
    COALESCE(SUM(total_revenue), 0) AS Total_Revenue
FROM (
    SELECT
        event_date,
        event_name,
        user_pseudo_id,
        (SELECT STRING_AGG(item_name, '; ') FROM UNNEST(items)) AS item_names,
        (SELECT STRING_AGG(item_category, '; ') FROM UNNEST(items)) AS item_category,
        (SELECT COALESCE(SUM(item_revenue_in_usd), 0) FROM UNNEST(items)) AS total_revenue,
        (SELECT value.int_value FROM UNNEST(event_params) WHERE key = 'ga_session_id') AS session_id
    FROM
        'xxxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxx
    WHERE
        event_date >= '20230101'
) grouped_data
GROUP BY
    event_date,
    event_name


Table is already Flatten in the array
